# RecyclerView: scrollToPosition not working

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have a simple project displaying user text messages. I am currently not able to scroll the RecyclerView to the last received text message.

My recyclerView is inside a very simple activity using the Coordinator layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@color/background"
tools:context="com.myproject.myproject.MessageActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_message" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the content_message.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.textbutler.textbutler.MessageActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_message">

<!-- some views here -->

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/content_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<!-- some views here -->
</LinearLayout>
```

The activity load the data through a basic loader. I force the access to the recyclerview on the UI thread and with a delay (just in case)

```
public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int URL_LOADER = 0;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
private MessageAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    initializeList(savedInstanceState);
}

private void initializeList(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (recyclerView == null) {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.content_text);

        if (recyclerView == null)
            return;

        if (layoutManager == null) {
            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
            layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        }

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        final Activity me = this;

        if (adapter == null) {
            adapter = new MessageAdapter(new ObservableCallback() {
                @Override
                public void callback() {
                    // this function is called right after the recyclerview received notifyDataSetChanged
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            me.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Log.d("ScrollingUI", "scrolltoposition " + adapter.getItemCount());
                                    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });
            SMSByUserLoader loader = new SMSByUserLoader(this, adapter);
            getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(URL_LOADER, savedInstanceState, loader);
        }

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

}

When I run this code, the RecyclerView is perfectly filled. After a second I have the correct log but the view does not changed.
I already found various answers to this issue, but none of them seems to work in my case.

Scrolling in the RecyclerView perfectly works.

Comment: Try recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount()-1) or recyclerView.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(...)

Comment: I already tried and nothing happened

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You used `layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true)` and `layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true)` in order to start your list from the end. So, if I understand it correctly, the list starts now from position `adapter.getItemCount() - 1` and your list shouldn't scroll. Maybe you should try `...scrollToPosition(0)`.

Answer (score 14):

I have the same problem and `smoothScrollToPosition` method solve it:

```
 RecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(postion);
```

Comment: SmoothScrollToPosition does solve this issue, however, for very large lists this is a terrible UX experience.

Answer (score 9):

Inspired by [@omid-jafarinezhad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43656311/1074998), I need to use `smoothScrollToPosition`, but I still need it instant scroll to the end because it will looks weird if keep scrolling many items slowly. And my workaround is use both methods at sequence, i.e.:

```
        myRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
            }
        }, 50); //sometime not working, need some delay
```

This may seems like a hack but at least solve my problem at this time.

Comment: Lol! I see what you are trying to do. But this solution still will not work at times.

Comment: tks for your answer,it really solve my problem.but I've no idea why it occurs like this

Comment: This answer really helped, Thanks a lot 林果皞 and stackoverflow

Answer (score 7):

My problem was that my RecyclerView was inside a **NestedScrollView**.
I removed the NestedScrollView, and scrollToPosition() worked.

Comment: How can we fix this without removing the nested recycler view ?

Comment: It is the NestedScrollView that I removed

Comment: Sorry. Actually my question was, how to fix this issue without removing the NestedScrollView ?

Comment: The scrolling should be done on the NestedScrollView. See:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76544884/1934673

Answer (score 1):

```
 private val delayShowRunnable by lazy{
    object:Runnable{
        override fun run() {
            rv_content?.alpha=1f
        }
    }
}

private   val  linearSmoothScroller by lazy{
   object: LinearSmoothScroller(context){

         override fun onTargetFound(targetView: View, state: RecyclerView.State, action: Action) {
           super.onTargetFound(targetView, state, action)
           rv_content?.postDelayed(delayShowRunnable,50)
       }
       override fun calculateTimeForDeceleration(dx: Int): Int {
           return  1//set max speed
       }

       override fun calculateTimeForScrolling(dx: Int): Int {
           return 1  //set max speed
       }
    }
}

rv_content?.alpha=0f  //hide listview before scroll finish 
 
 linearSmoothScroller.targetPosition = pos
        (rv_content?.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager?)?.startSmoothScroll(linearSmoothScroller)
```

scroll position change will not be reflected until the next layout call.
so we should use <smoothscrollToPosition()> , find out target view.

Answer (score 1):

Always use -1 if you want to scroll to the end of your adapter
`recyclerView.scrollToPosition(chatAdapter.getItemCount()-1);`

Answer (score 0):

1. In a usual case you can wait some time till a RecyclerView can scroll.

   ```
   binding.recyclerView.postDelayed({
       binding.recyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapter.itemCount - 1)
   }, 100)
   ```

Instead of 100 ms you can use numbers from 0 to 1000, depending on a device.

2. If you use [Paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview) adapter it can request a new page. When you try to scroll a RecyclerView the adapter isn't ready (new items haven't not been added). So you can add a subscriber to request finish and then scroll the list (probably after a pause like in the first case).